# R: Switching between OpenBLAS and ATLAS within a R sesssion using Ubuntu

Tags: r

Is there any way to switch between OpenBLAS and ATLAS libraries from a running R session? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Thank you

Comment: R has to be compiled using those libraries. You cannot switch in running R session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R documentation states that in order to [use another BLAS library](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Linear-algebra), this needs to be specified configure time. This means that R needs to be rebuilt from source if you want to switch libraries. So, it is not possible to switch between BLAS libraries in a running R session.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

no need to rebuild R, but yes do it when R is not running. See [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2013/07/09/for-faster-r-use-openblas-instead-better-than-atlas-trivial-to-switch-to-on-ubuntu/).